# Can I get the p values from emmeans of glmmTMB?

Tags: model, p-value, emmeans

I build a model with the glmmTMB function and calculated my significances with the emmeans function. The tukey test didn´t work as my data set was too big. I´d like to get p-values for my significances though. Is that possible from the emmeans function?

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing what your data is like or what your calls to glmmTMB or emmeans were, this is a difficult question to answer.

Presuming you are looking for the pairwise comparisons of each treatment level you should be able to get p-values for pairwise tests by using the following call:

`emmeans(model,pairwise ~ A * B)`

Where "model" is you glmm, and "A" and "B" are your factors (of course you may have more).

Is this what you want, and does this solve your problem?